# How to denormalize a capacitor?

Tags: capacitance

What does a denormalizing and normalizing a capacitor mean? I am confused with  the difference of normalizing and denormalizing a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

These apply to scaling a standard "Normalized" filter design using some close to , or equal to C=1F value.

The filter characteristics depend on ratios of passive parts to achieve textbook performance if the values in the scaled or denormalized values behave close to ideal.

Then to design the filter from a standard like Sallens & Keys you scale the Impedance and frequency of desired input Z and simple breakpoint by scaling the capacitor impedance and R values.

> RLC ratios are standardized for hundreds of different filter types and characteristics, both passive and active with many books on this subject.